# How is an empty listview rendered?

Tags: android, listview, layout

If a listview is not given any items, how is it rendered? Will it still expand to fill the space in the layout allotted to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will still fill the space, but instead of displaying a list you can have it display another view.  Here's an example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/GLFrame"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:text="@string/no_songs_found"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000" />
```

The key here is the `"@android:id/empty"` and `"@android:id/list"` ids.  These tells Android that it should either display the list or the other view if the list is empty.

Comment: BTW, if my main view layout contains a listview that is just *part* of the layout (i.e. there are other widgets above and below it), should I still extend ListView or should I enscapsulate that some other way?

Comment: You can still use a ListActivity.